# How to use ViewModel in RecyclerView correctly?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, android-livedata

*This Line is wrong **adapter = ItemAdapter(applicationContext,userViewModel.getListUsers())***

**Because the adapter parameters context: Context, arrayList: ArrayList (but not MutableLiveData) **

*I don’t know what to do about it, and I’m not entirely sure if I am using the LiveData correctly.*

**My Adapter**

```
class ItemAdapter(var context: Context, private var arrayList: ArrayList<NumberModel>):RecyclerView.Adapter<ItemAdapter.ItemHolder>() {

override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ItemHolder{

    val itemHolder = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(
        R.layout.grid_layout_list_item,
        parent,
        false
    )
    return ItemHolder(itemHolder)
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ItemHolder, position: Int) {

    var positionOfNumber:NumberModel = arrayList.get(position)
    holder.textOfNumber.text = positionOfNumber.numberOfElement

   holder.button.setOnClickListener {
       var positionForDelete = holder.adapterPosition
       arrayList.removeAt(positionForDelete)
       notifyItemRemoved(positionForDelete)
       notifyItemRangeChanged(positionForDelete,arrayList.size)
   }
}

override fun getItemCount(): Int {
    return arrayList.size
}

class ItemHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
    var textOfNumber = itemView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.numberTextView)
    var button:Button = itemView.findViewById(R.id.buttonClick)
}
```

}

**MainActivity**

```
recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerViewList)

    gridLayoutManager = GridLayoutManager(applicationContext,2,LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL,false)
    recyclerView?.layoutManager = gridLayoutManager
    recyclerView?.setHasFixedSize(true)
    recyclerView?.adapter = adapter

    userViewModel.getListUsers().observe(this, Observer {
        it?.let {
            adapter = ItemAdapter(applicationContext,userViewModel.getListUsers())
        }
    })
}
```

**ViewModel**

```
class MainActivityViewModel : ViewModel() {
var elementsList: MutableLiveData<ArrayList<NumberModel>> = MutableLiveData()

init {
    elementsList.value = setElements()
}

fun getListUsers() = elementsList

private fun setElements() : ArrayList<NumberModel> {
    var itemArrayList:ArrayList<NumberModel> = ArrayList()
    itemArrayList.add(NumberModel("1"))
    itemArrayList.add(NumberModel("2"))
    itemArrayList.add(NumberModel("3"))
    itemArrayList.add(NumberModel("4"))
    itemArrayList.add(NumberModel("5"))
    itemArrayList.add(NumberModel("6"))
    itemArrayList.add(NumberModel("7"))
    itemArrayList.add(NumberModel("8"))
    itemArrayList.add(NumberModel("9"))
    itemArrayList.add(NumberModel("10"))
    return itemArrayList
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Reason for `Because the adapter parameters context: Context, arrayList: ArrayList (but not MutableLiveData)` this error.
we are passing the MutableLiveData instead of ArrayList. so we need to pass the ArrayList as the second parameter.

```
userViewModel.getListUsers().observe(this, Observer {
        it?.let { list->
            adapter = ItemAdapter(applicationContext,list)
        }
    })
```

userViewModel.getListUsers() will give the ArrayList so we can pass this to get the instance of ItemAdapter

instead of passing the `applicationContext` we can give `this`or `requireActivity()` (will give the MainActivity context),
if we pass the applicationContext, we may lead to a `memory leak` we have to pass the right context to the object.